# Community scoped variables in Salesforce Portals

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

**Scenario:**
I have some Lightning Web Components that I'm sharing across 2 different Communities oriented to 2 different group of external users. In order to differentiate the behavior of the components for the different groups; I'm specifying external targets in the LWC meta-xml, like the following:

```
    <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
        <property label="Portal Type" name="portalType" type="String" datasource="GroupA,GroupB" default="GroupA"/>        
    </targetConfig>
```

This approach works, but I think is repetitive for multiple LWC and a potentially a maintenance problem if the community scales.

**Question:**
Is there any kind of "Community scoped variables" where I can reference all my LWC to?, no luck when googling this. I would like to have a central place where APEX or LWC could read the community characteristics and render accordingly. Any help or suggestions is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make a custom metadata type that has all the various settings you need for your components and add a record for each community.

Then in the component take a settings name parameter from the experience builder and pass it to some apex that looks for the appropriately named metadata record and sends back your config and finishes init.

So you'll just need to set one property in the builder for each component, which config to load.